# Sorting months from current in array with objects

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array with objects:

> Array (
>     [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 64 [name] => January [alias] => january [description] => 01)
>     [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 64 [name] => January [alias] => january [description] => 01)
>     [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65 [name] => February [alias] => february [description] => 02)
>    ...

How could I sort it from current month, and then naturaly way, so for today it would be:
October, November, December, January ..

So for this example it would be:

> Array (
>     [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 73 [name] => October [alias] => october [description] => 10)
>     [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 64 [name] => January [alias] => january [description] => 01)
>     [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 74 [name] => November [alias] => november [description] => 11)
>    ...

I don'thave idea how to do this.

Comment: Is your array fixed? in other words, always the first element january, second element feb etc?

Comment: [Here's](http://ideone.com/wgim4o) more generalized solution for your problem. But it has some overhead.

Comment: And [Here's](http://ideone.com/D4A56D) optimized solution (removed `array_search` in ordering month array to increase performance).

Comment: Please review your question. The array you're asking about is technically *not* possible in PHP. And a very simple solution is by creating a new array based on the old one cutting it in half and putting the parts together again swapped, see http://php.net/array_splice and http://php.net/array_merge .

Comment: Example here: https://eval.in/private/b731ae05c4de16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object array is always starting with jan, has 12 elements one for each month, try this, which is probably not the most efficient way of doing it:

```
$curMonth = date("n")-1;
$out = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++)
  {
  $index = ( $i + $curMonth ) % 12;
  $out[$i] = $YourObjectArray[$index]
  }

print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if month "smaller" than now then put it into end of array:

```
$arr[] = array('name'=>'jan', 'desc' => '01');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'feb', 'desc' => '02');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'mar', 'desc' => '03');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'apr', 'desc' => '04');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'may', 'desc' => '05');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'jun', 'desc' => '06');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'jul', 'desc' => '07');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'aug', 'desc' => '08');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'sep', 'desc' => '09');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'oct', 'desc' => '10');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'nov', 'desc' => '11');
$arr[] = array('name'=>'dec', 'desc' => '12');

foreach($arr as $i=>$y){
    if($y['desc'] != date('m')){
        unset($x[$i]);
        $arr[] = $y;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
```